# ARM M0+ exception stack pointer after bootloader relocation

Tags: pointers, memory, stack

I'm using Crossworks as my development platform.

I don't think I did it - but the bootloader I wrote placed the "main" stack in low memory.  Later in time (after a Crossworks upgrade) - I wrote the application code and the linker placed the stack in high memory.

After 3 days of debugging I discovered my root-cause of memory corruption in my application.

The Application was using the stack pointer defined at reset (relocated address zero - 0x4000) which was high memory but the interrupt code was using the stack pointer from the bootloader (low memory) which was corrupting my data down there.

Question - ARM literature says (I'm not using the "process" stack) - that the application and exception handlers use the "main" stack.  The bootloader loads the SP from the first word and jumps to the address contained in the second word.  The startup code then sets the stack pointer again.  So if the startup code is setting the stack pointer ("main" stack) and THAT is the stack that the application uses, HOW is the exception handler still using the stack pointer from the bootloader?

Given that I have a bootloader using a stack in low memory and an application using a stack in high memory -- how can I have the application exception use the same stack pointer that is currently considered the "main" stack?

I have product in the field so I have to correct the application's exception stack pointer and not just create a new bootloader that uses a high memory stack.

I hope I explained this clearer than mud.

Comment: I check on my bootloader -- I used both a "main" stack and a "process" stack -- so that may be part of my problem. -- In the application - I'm only using a "main" stack.

Answer (score 0):

The bootloader had used the "process" stack so the control register had bit 1 set.

I cleared the control register in the relocated application so that one one stack is used and my issue is resolved.